# Why is this boxshadow not appearing?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm working on a little widget and for some reason I cannot get the boxshadow to appear. I've set it on the container and I have no idea why it isn't working. I'm guessing it has something to do with ClipPath?

```
Widget _routineBox({bool isNight}) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)))),
    child: Container(
      height: 70.0,
      width: 200.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border(
          left:
              BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 8.0),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
            spreadRadius: 0.3,
            blurRadius: 10,
            offset: Offset(2, 2), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Center(
          child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Text("Your Text",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.black)),
      )),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to wrap the whole thing in another container and put the boxShadow inside that outer container like so:

```
  Widget _routineBox({bool isNight}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 0.3,
              blurRadius: 10,
              offset: Offset(2, 2),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)))),
          child: Container(
            height: 150.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border(
                left: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 8.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: new Text("Your Text",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.black)),
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put **ClipPath** widget in a **Material** widget and give it an elevation like this:

```
child: Material(
          elevation: 10,
          child: ClipPath(
    ))
```

Here's the code:

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
    child: Material(
      elevation: 10,
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)))),
        child: Container(
          height: 70.0,
          width: 200.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(
              left: BorderSide(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 8.0),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                spreadRadius: 0.3,
                blurRadius: 10,
                offset: Offset(2, 2), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Text("Your Text",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.black)),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this using a box shadow? Elevation limits the customization of the shadow for what I want to do.